# Finding fractals by using an array

Tags: mql4

I would like to find a swing low btwn two swing highs under a specified period.

ifractals find the shifts for individual candles but not where the fractals form.

I would like to find the immediate swing high that forms before a swing low.
When the swing high formed b4 the swing low is violated by price ,we find the immediate swing high formed.

Comment: ICT 2022 Model? Try better with Zigzag and store all the values in an array, then compare all the prices with the current price. If not, use Fractals as well, store the previous fractal and compare it.

Comment: My problem now is how would i write a script/line of code to store this previous fractal.

Comment: Or how would u create an array to store the zigzag values?